# Speed Up Python Function that Extracts Text from PDF

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, coding-efficiency, pdftotext

I am currently working on a program that scrapes text from tens of thousands of PDFs of court opinions. I am relatively new to Python and am trying to make this code as efficient as possible. I have gathered from *many* posts on this site and elsewhere that I should be trying to vectorize my code, but I have tried three methods for doing so without results.

My reprex uses these packages and this sample data.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import pdftotext
import wget

df = pd.DataFrame({'OpinionText': [""], 'URLs': ["https://cases.justia.com/federal/appellate-courts/ca6/20-6226/20-6226-2021-09-17.pdf?ts=1631908842"]})
df = pd.concat([df]*50, ignore_index=True)
```

I started by defining this function, which downloads the PDF, extracts the text, deletes the PDF, and then returns the text.

```
def Link2Text(Link):
    OpinionPDF = wget.download(Link, "Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
    with open(OpinionPDF, "rb") as f:
        pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
    OpinionText = "\n\n".join(pdf)
    if os.path.exists("Temporary_Opinion.pdf"):
        os.remove("Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
    return(OpinionText)
```

The first way that I called the function, which works but is very slow, is:

```
df['OpinionText'] = df['URLs'].apply(Link2Text)
```

Based on what I read about vectorization, I tried calling the function using:

```
df['OpinionText'] = Link2Text(df['URLs'])

#and, alternatively:

df['OpinionText'] = Link2Text(df['URLs'].values)
```

Both of these returned the same error, which is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brendanbernicker/Downloads/Reprex for SO Vectorization Q.py", line 22, in <module>
    df['OpinionText'] = Link2Text(df['URLs'])
  File "/Users/brendanbernicker/Downloads/Reprex for SO Vectorization Q.py", line 10, in Link2Text
    OpinionPDF = wget.download(Link, "Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wget.py", line 505, in download
    prefix = detect_filename(url, out)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wget.py", line 483, in detect_filename
    if url:
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1442, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
[Finished in 0.683s]
```

I gather that this is saying that Python does not know what to do with the input because it is a vector, so I tried replacing the call with the one below and got this traceback.

```
df['OpinionText'] = Link2Text(df['URLs'].item)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/brendanbernicker/Downloads/Reprex for SO Vectorization Q.py", line 22, in <module>
    df['OpinionText'] = Link2Text(df['URLs'].item)
  File "/Users/brendanbernicker/Downloads/Reprex for SO Vectorization Q.py", line 10, in Link2Text
    OpinionPDF = wget.download(Link, "Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wget.py", line 505, in download
    prefix = detect_filename(url, out)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wget.py", line 484, in detect_filename
    names["url"] = filename_from_url(url) or ''
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wget.py", line 230, in filename_from_url
    fname = os.path.basename(urlparse.urlparse(url).path)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 372, in urlparse
    url, scheme, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(url, scheme)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 124, in _coerce_args
    return _decode_args(args) + (_encode_result,)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 108, in _decode_args
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
  File "/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/urllib/parse.py", line 108, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(x.decode(encoding, errors) if x else '' for x in args)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I tried adding `.decode('utf-8')` to my function call and within the function to the input, but got the same traceback for both. At this point, I do not know what else to try to speed up my code.

I also tried `numpy.vectorize` with the version that works using `.apply`, but it dramatically slowed down the execution. I am assuming that those two should not be used together.

In the interest of completeness, based on some excellent answers here, I also tried:

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def Link2Text(Link, Opinion):
    res = np.empty(Link.shape)
    for i in range(length(Link)):
        OpinionPDF = wget.download(Link[i], "Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
        with open(OpinionPDF, "rb") as f:
            pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f)
        OpinionText = "\n\n".join(pdf)
        if os.path.exists("Temporary_Opinion.pdf"):
            os.remove("Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
        Opinion[i] = OpinionText

Link2Text(df['URLs'].values, df['OpinionText'].values)
```

I gather that this did not work because numba does not work with the packages I am calling inside the function and is intended more for mathematical operations. If that is not correct and I should be trying to use numba for this, please let me know.

Comment: What is the reason for using Pandas here? It is not a general purpose high performance container but is optimized for efficient processing on numerical datasets. You should first describe what you want to achieve: what is the input data, how you can access it, what is the processing and what shall be the result...

Comment: ... If I have correctly understood, you have a bunch of URLs to download, extract text for pdf files and build something (this part I could not exactly guess). A more common way would be to use threading for the download part because it is an IO bound operation, and then use plain Python containers (lists, dicts, tuples, sets) to process your data.

Comment: Thank you for the questions. It sounds like I should not be using Pandas here, which I mainly only used because I am familiar with it. The input data is a list of URLs for PDFs of court opinions. The goal is to download the PDF from each URL, extract its text, and save the text into a list that contains the text of each opinion. The code I have written does that, but it is very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the advice in the comments. I did not use pandas, used list comprehension, and rewrote this as:

```
def pdftotext(path):
    args = r'pdftotext -layout -q Temporary_Opinion.pdf Opinion_Text.txt'
    cp = sp.run(
      args, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.DEVNULL,
      check=True, text=True
    )
    return cp.stdout

def Link2Text(Link):
    OpinionPDF = wget.download(Link, "Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
    pdftotext("Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
    OpinionText = io.open("Opinion_Text.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    OpinionText = OpinionText.readlines()
    if os.path.exists("Temporary_Opinion.pdf"):
        os.remove("Temporary_Opinion.pdf")
    if os.path.exists("Opinion_Text.txt"):
        os.remove("Opinion_Text.txt")
    return(OpinionText)

Opinions = [Link2Text(item) for item in URLs]
```

This is considerably faster and does exactly what I need. Thanks to everyone who offered advice on this! The next step will be using threading and layout analysis to speed up the IO and clean the data.